# Sorting a custom linked list with <algorithm> sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, list, sorting, linked-list

I've written my own doubly linked list, complete with begin() and end() iterators. These work fine with traversing the list using a loop. However, as part of my assignment, I need to sort the list according to certain criteria. Since we haven't yet covered the chapter on sorting algorithms, we are allowed to use the sort function defined in the  header. But sort(list.begin(), list.end(), compare) returns quite a few errors related to my iterator class:

```
error: no type named iterator_category
error: no type named value_type
error: no type named difference_type
error: no type named pointer
error: no type named reference
```

Additionally, I receive errors regarding the + and - operators. I understand how to define value_type, pointer, and reference, but I'm lost when it comes to the others. Is what I'm trying to do possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible, but can be somewhat painful, as you'll end up writing a fair amount of boilerplate code.

Worse, when you're done, it won't work very well -- `std::sort` doesn't absolutely *require* random access iterators, but with (say) bidirectional iterators, performance will generally be fairly poor. Just for example, it's poor enough that (unlike most standard containers) `std::list` has a `sort` member function to make up for the fact that `std::sort` works poorly on linked lists.

Basically, `operator+` and `operator-` just advance a pointer N items forward or backward. typically you overload `operator++` to advance by one, something like `pos = pos -> next;` (and `operator--` uses something like `pos = pos->prev;`. Then you can use `std::advance` or `std::next` to advance by more than one item at a time (but be aware: for a bidirectional iterator it'll do that by calling `++` or `--` repeatedly -- one of the reasons for poor performance).

Comment: So, it would probably be best to just write my own sorting algorithm, haha?

Comment: @RobRob: Unfortunately, yes. Better still: just avoid linked lists, where are rarely useful anyway.

Comment: Ah, okay. I would love to, honestly, but since this is for an assignment, I am bound to a linked list, haha.